# Invalid Binary while submitting the app on app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

When I am submitting the iPhone and iPad apps, the iPhone app went through just fine while iTunes Connect showed an "Invalid Binary" for the iPad app. There weren't any other explanations. The build did pass the validation and submission from xCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error, the provisioning profile for the project and traget was not set properly. thats it i set the distribution provisioning profile and build it, it works.